# Deploy Polymer Dart application

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dart2js

Is there any way how to build pure JavaScript (or production ready) Polymer application?

I've just built polymer application, but I have some issues:

- in build directory are buildLogs files, dart files + whole packages
- files are not minified, dart files (if anyone need them) are not obfuscated
- I need some packages/polymer/src/build/log_injector.css deep in packages folder
- Every single polymer element has it's own dart file - unminified, unobfuscated

In non polymer application I've used

```
transformers:
 - $dart2js:
     checked: false
     minify: true
     verbose: false
```

and ommited packages folder (I've just need to copy browser.js and iterop.js)

Comment: Have you tried running `pub build` from the command line interface?

Answer (score 0):

As Gunter mentioned in the comments, you need to go to your command line with your project's directory current (the directory containing `pubspec.yaml`), and run `pub build`. The default behavior of the command-line build is to minify and run in release mode instead of checked mode. Running Pub Build from within Dart Editor does not have these defaults.